# How to make a scrollable div with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add an image into my div inside bottom to top when I click the add button. Now it is working, but my problem was the div does not scroll. What I am doing wrong?

[**JSFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ftev/5/)

**HTML**

```
 <button id="add_content">Add</button>
 <div class="image_panel"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .image_panel {
     width:100%;
     height:300px;
     border:1px solid red;
     overflow-y:scroll;
  }
  #add_content{
     float:left;
  }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var smallimg_count=0;
  var bottom=0;
  $("#add_content").click(function() {
    smallimg_count++;
    bottom=bottom+20;      
    var insert_html_small = '<div id="imageGrid_' + smallimg_count + '"  class="imageGrid_small"  >
                               <img class="resize1" id="resize_' + smallimg_count + '" src="http://webbies.dk/assets/templates/SudoSlider/images/toolbox_designer.png" style="bottom:' + bottom + 'px;" />
                             </div>';
    $(insert_html_small).appendTo(".image_panel");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that I see is that the image you are adding has an absolute position inline style (from your JSFiddle)

e.g.

```
style="bottom:' +   bottom + 'px; position: absolute;'
```

Therefore it's in a different stacking context than the div

Removing it seems to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ftev/12/

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var smallimg_count = 0;
    var bottom = 0;
    $("#add_content").click(function () {
        smallimg_count++;
        bottom = bottom + 20;
        var insert_html_small = '<div id="imageGrid_' + smallimg_count + '"  class="imageGrid_small"  ><img   class="resize1" id="resize_' + smallimg_count + '" src="http://webbies.dk/assets/templates/SudoSlider/images/toolbox_designer.png" /></div>';
        $(insert_html_small).appendTo(".image_panel");
    });
});
```

If you want to add it bottom up, then you can use `prependTo`, see this JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ftev/15/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var smallimg_count = 0;
    var bottom = 0;
    $("#add_content").click(function () {
        smallimg_count++;
        bottom = bottom + 20;
        var insert_html_small = '<div id="imageGrid_' + smallimg_count + '"  class="imageGrid_small"  >' + smallimg_count + '<img   class="resize1" id="resize_' + smallimg_count + '" src="http://webbies.dk/assets/templates/SudoSlider/images/toolbox_designer.png" /></div>';
        $(insert_html_small).prependTo(".image_panel");
    });
});
```

Comment: but it add top to bottom i want to add bottom to top

Comment: i don't know and i don't have that much reputation

Comment: This still isn't doing what the original code did: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ftev/9/ Since the OP selected the answer I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @isherwood true, but I'll let the OP take it from there

Comment: @EranMedan Thanks for your valuable answer

Comment: @Seenu thanks for a very well formed question, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an absolute positioned image, inside a div which is not relative positioned.

First of all, add `position:relative;` to the `.image_panel` class style

What you will notice now, is that the image is positioned relative to the div. 
If you want to test the scrollbar, i would recommend you to use a margin instead of the absolute positioning on your image.

Like, `margin-top:900px;`

**Css**

```
  .image_panel
    {
     width:100%;
     height:300px;
     border:1px solid red;
     overflow-y:scroll;
     position:relative;
     }
   #add_content{
     float:left;
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
var smallimg_count=0;
var bottom=500;
$("#add_content").click(function(){
smallimg_count++;
bottom=bottom+20;      
var insert_html_small = '<div id="imageGrid_' +   smallimg_count + '"  class="imageGrid_small"  ><img   class="resize1" id="resize_' + smallimg_count + '" src="http://webbies.dk/assets/templates/SudoSlider/images/toolbox_designer.png" style="margin-top:' +   bottom + 'px;"    /></div>';
$(insert_html_small).appendTo(".image_panel");
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3gzaW/

Best regards.
Jonas

Comment: Fiddle's not adding images for me.

Comment: #isherwood try scrolling after clicking ADD

Comment: I see it, but that's not quite what the OP was after. :-)

Comment: i want to add bottom to top

Comment: I am sorry, i dont quiete understand what OP means with "Add bottom to top" then.

Answer (score 0):

Your images:

```
<img class="resize1" id="resize_3" src="http://webbies.dk/assets/templates/SudoSlider/images/toolbox_designer.png" style="bottom:60px; position: absolute;;">
```

Take away the position:absolute; (make it relative, or remove it entirely)

Comment: Then they don't lay overlapped like they do now.

Comment: i change position:relative didn't add bottom to top